# retrieving database images using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

I am trying to retrieve images from my database, everything else works and is retrieved ok from the database except the images, does anyone have any idea what im doing wrong? the code im using is shown below:

```
  $query = "SELECT p.name, p.image, p.price, p.description, p.category_id, ci.quantity   
    FROM products p 
        LEFT JOIN cart_items ci 
            ON p.id=ci.product_id 
    WHERE p.id=? 
    LIMIT 0,1";

 $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
 $stmt->execute();

 $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $name = $row['name'];
 $image = $row['image'];
 $price = $row['price'];
 $description = $row['description'];
 $category_id = $row['category_id'];
 $quantity = $row['quantity'];
  ?>
 <!-- HTML form for updating a product -->
<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered' style='margin:1em 0 0 0;'>

<tr>
    <td style='width:30%;'>Name<?php echo "<div class='product-id' style='display:none;'>{$id}</div>"; ?></td>
    <td class='product-name' style='width:70%;'><?php echo $name; ?></td>
</tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Image</td>
    <td><?php echo '<img src=""images/'.$image.'" />'; ?></td>
</tr>
```

It currently shows a blank box when this is in the web browser, it doesnt seem to be finding the images which are in a folder called images

Comment: When you inspect element the image, does it show the correct `src`?

Comment: The image names in your database aren't, by any chance, just the image names without file-extensions are they?

Comment: <img src="" images="" cesar.jpg"=""></img> i inspected element and this is what it is finding, the image cesar.jpg is in a folder called images

Comment: the images in my database appear images/cesar.jpg

Comment: Are you sure that file exists in a place that your web server can serve it up? In your PHP code you need to produce a working URL, but it's hard to say if that's going to work unless there's some way you can check here. Also watch your syntax, HTML can be forgiving but mistakes matter: `""` in that last `<img>` tag looks out of place.

Comment: @lauren you have a `"` after `src="` remove that, also if your db column have the value as `images/cesar.jpg` remove `images/` too.

Comment: I have removed the "" so it is like this : <td><?php echo '<img src=images/'.$image.'" />'; ?></td>                  i have inspected this element and i am now left with 
 
<img src="" images/images/cesar.jpg""></img>

Comment: @lauren replace `echo '<img src=""images/'.$image.'" />';` with `echo '<img src="'.$image.'" />';`

Comment: excellent that worked thank you very much @Alex